# Facebook Oauth is failing in Iframe in IE and Firefox

Tags: facebook-oauth

I am using Facebook Oauth. My application is in iframe. Following is my initial Oauth URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXX&scope=offline_access,publish_stream

redirect_uri is https.

In IE8 I am getting following error page:

[Initially it shows Go To Facebook.com link][1]

![Then it shows following error page][2]

This content cannot be displayed in a frame

In Firefox it shows empty white page. So Facebook Oauth is not working in IE as well as in Firefox also. I did find some posts on your site. but those didn't help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Does your site work in any browser? It's my understanding that you can't do FB oauth inside of an iframe.

Comment: No, it is not working in any browser. but last year it was working in all browsers. Did Facebook change anything for Oauth in iframe?

Comment: Yes- they stopped allowing it because of the potential for exploitation, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Do we have any official post/blog from Facebook on the same on their site?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/:

> **iframe**: For use by apps when running inside an iframe within a Canvas page on Facebook. Displays the dialog within a lightbox-style overlay. Because of the risk of clickjacking, this is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid access_token. *This mode is not supported by the OAuth Dialog.*

Even though you are not specifying `iframe` as the display type, you are loading the dialog inside of an iframe, and facebook detects this to prevent clickjacking.

One good way around this is to open a popup window that handles authentication:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&client_id=...');
</script>
```

or something similar (open a URL on your site that does the redirect, etc).